# how can i remove specify row from a jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with some information in it. Now I want remove a specify row from it but it have exception.

I wrote below code:

```
jtable table = new jtable(model);

 model.setDataVector(str2, str1);

model.fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
     model.removeRow(row);


//str2,str1 are verctor
```

what is problem?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
    at java.util.Vector.removeElementAt(Vector.java:511)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.removeRow(DefaultTableModel.java:446)
    at project1.SportMan.jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(SportMan.java:481)
    at project1.SportMan.access$1000(SportMan.java:29)
    at project1.SportMan$6.actionPerformed(SportMan.java:350)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:809)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:850)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6267)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: can you paste the code how you are creating table and where deleting the row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0` is a pretty clear indicator that the table is already empty.

Comment: my table wasn't empty but i didn't use from model.setvector

Answer (score 1):

apart from my comment: model.fireSomething is *not* the means to soSomething (and is not meant for usage outside of the model). Instead, call model.removeRow(row) - if supported by the concrete implementation, as f.i. DefaultTableModel - and everything will simply work (provided that row is a valid row index).

addendum: Jim is completely right - the stackstrace shows that the model is empty